# select dict object based on value

Tags: python

This is how my JSON object looks like:

```
[{
    'Description': 'Description 1',
    'OutputKey': 'OutputKey 1',
    'OutputValue': 'OutputValue 1'
},
{
    'Description': 'Description 2',
    'OutputKey': 'OutputKey 2',
    'OutputValue': 'OutputValue 2'
},
{
    'Description': 'Description 3',
    'OutputKey': 'OutputKey 3',
    'OutputValue': 'OutputValue 3'
},
{
    'Description': 'Description 4',
    'OutputKey': 'OutputKey 4',
    'OutputValue': 'OutputValue 4'
},
{
    'Description': 'Description 5',
    'OutputKey': 'OutputKey 5',
    'OutputValue': 'OutputValue 5'
},
{
    'Description': 'Description 6',
    'OutputKey': 'OutputKey 6',
    'OutputValue': 'OutputValue 6'
}]
```

How do i grab the dict object where OutputKey is 4 without looping thru?

`any(key['OutputKey'] == 'OutputKey 4' for key in myJSON)` returns true but i need it to grab the whole JSON object that belongs to that key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `next`:

```
next(key for key in myJSON if key['OutputKey'] == 'OutputKey 4')
```

However, if the "key" isn't present, then you'll get a `StopIteration` exception.  You can handle that as you normally would handle any other exception, or you can supply a "default" to `next`:

```
default = None  # or whatever...
next((key for key in myJSON if key['OutputKey'] == 'OutputKey 4'), default)
```

Note that this is still "looping through" all the items (except that it short circuits when it finds the right one).  If you really want to avoid a loop, you'll need a different data-structure:

```
dict_by_output_key = {key['OutputKey']: key for key in myJSON}
dict_by_output_key['OutputKey 4']
```

You still have to do 1 loop -- But once you've done it, you can do as many O(1) lookups as you want.  The cost is a little additional intermediate storage (memory).

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic answer. I am using the last approach. Is there a way I can make it return None when the key is not found or I need to just handle the exception?

Comment: @Asdfg -- `dict_by_output_key.get('OutputKey 4')` will return `None` or the result of the key lookup (if it exists)

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    next(key for key in myJSON if key['OutputKey'] == 'OutputKey 4')
except StopIteration:
    #code for the case where there is no such dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

A JSON Object is essentially a list of dictionaries. Therefore you need to use index notation to access one of the dictionaries, in this case myJSON[3]. Then inside the dictionary, call that dictionary's key so that it will return its value. So:

`myJSON[3]['OutputKey']`

will return OutputKey4.

Comment: Except you may not know which of the dictionaries is the one you're looking for without looking inside them.

Comment: True. I was assuming it was known, otherwise you would still have to loop through it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of dicts. If you know the index of the required dict, then you can index that list:

```
output_4 = myJSON[3]
```

Otherwise, you'll be looping through, even if the loop is not obvious (as with your `any` approach):

```
for d in myJSON:
    if d['OutputKey'] == 'OutputKey 4':
        result = d
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider using some kind of in-memory database to store the info in order to perform that kind of queries on your data.

For instance, I have used [TinyDB](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tinydb) in the past, which save the data in a file in JSON format. This is the code for the requested query using this module:

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
from tinydb.storages import MemoryStorage
db = TinyDB(storage=MemoryStorage)

db.insert_multiple([{
    'Description': 'Description 1',
    'OutputKey': 'OutputKey 1',
    'OutputValue': 'OutputValue 1'
},
{
    'Description': 'Description 2',
    'OutputKey': 'OutputKey 2',
    'OutputValue': 'OutputValue 2'
},
{
    'Description': 'Description 3',
    'OutputKey': 'OutputKey 3',
    'OutputValue': 'OutputValue 3'
},
{
    'Description': 'Description 4',
    'OutputKey': 'OutputKey 4',
    'OutputValue': 'OutputValue 4'
},
{
    'Description': 'Description 5',
    'OutputKey': 'OutputKey 5',
    'OutputValue': 'OutputValue 5'
},
{
    'Description': 'Description 6',
    'OutputKey': 'OutputKey 6',
    'OutputValue': 'OutputValue 6'
}])

q = Query()
print db.search(q.OutputKey == 'OutputKey 4')
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13823463)

Comment: Perhaps I should elaborate more, but IMHO I'm the only one who has gave a correct answer.  The other answers do iterations which goes against what was requested. I could be wrong, of course :)